How to check size of a pickle or number of contents it has
I made a pickle long time ago and want to use what's inside it, but I have to make sure I have the exact amount [8752 pickled images] inside it. I tried usual python function like len()but it failed. But when I try printing one of it's content like an array, it does output an array that looks like an array of images and that apparently cannot be converted into visible images (like .jpeg) again.
How do I make sure I have all images inside?
I tried printing the images per array number and it outputs an array of arrays, I tried checking usual way of checking size in python with 'len' but it outputs 1080 instead of expected 8752 image content.

Edit 1:
The codes for loading pickle
#load pickle
with open("rivergate_image.pkl", "rb") as f:

    river_images = pickle.load(f)

print(river_images[0])
print(len(river_images))

edit 2:
### print(river_images) output
[[[ 27 147 145]
  [ 30 150 148]
  [ 28 148 146]
  ...
  [ 61 178 169]
  [ 63 177 169]
  [ 65 176 167]]

 [[ 24 144 142]
  [ 24 144 142]
  [ 24 144 142]
  ...
  [ 59 179 170]
  [ 63 177 169]
  [ 65 176 169]]

 [[ 32 152 150]
...
  ...
  [ 37 142 145]
  [ 36 141 144]
  [ 35 140 143]]]
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

Edit 3:
output of
print(len(river_images))

are
1080

output of
print(type(river_images))

are
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

output of
print(river_images.shape)

are
(1080, 1420, 3)


Rather looks like one ok image. What happens if you try to load another?

@nocomment it shows another image with different array, but when I try uh..let's say..opencv imshow, it's a bit one dimensional in practice. So I don't know if it's still an image or how do I know there's still 8752 "image" of it?

Please add the code as text so we can copy&paste it

sure, do you need the pickle too?

No. What does print(river_images) print?

added to the question, it's a truncated of 'images' arrays

Oh sorry, I meant print(type(river_images)).

It's <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

And print(river_images.shape)?

it's (1080, 1420, 3) ? Ohh...

Please still put those last two things into the question.

Btw thank you for being very responsive, that was a pleasure. With others, we often have to wait very long for replies or even never get any, which is frustrating.

No problem haha, it's because I'm desperately needed these images so I waited. Thanks for answering too, very helpful

Looks like you dumped the images separately into the file, as NumPy arrays (1080x1420 pixels of red+green+blue value).
Try loading and counting until the end of the file. Example:
import pickle

# Create test file
with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as f:
  for thing in 'foobar':
    pickle.dump(thing, f)

# Load/count
with open('test.pkl', 'rb') as f:
  n = 0
  try:
    while True:
      thing = pickle.load(f)
      n += 1
      print(repr(thing))
  except EOFError:
    print(n, 'things')

Output (Attempt This Online!):
'f'
'o'
'o'
'b'
'a'
'r'
6 things


exactly 8752 things inside, thanks! So is it still filled an RGB images then? And so it is true that pickle don't have dedicated function for checking the sizes of it. Why can't I opencv.imshow()  as if it was a .jpeg? Do I need to deserialize it first?

@RedSean I don't think pickle has a function for counting the dumped entries. You could've, when creating the file, dumped a single list containing the images. Then a single load would return the list and you could get its length. But that would require holding all images in memory at the same time, which could be a problem.

@RedSean I'm not familiar with opencv. I assume it has some function that takes such a NumPy array and gives you an "image" object that you can then work with.

I did try that using lists to create pickles and I got memory problem, but okay at least it is still an image I can use. Okay I will try to look for it. Thanks

One more question, why was it return (1080 x1420 x 3) numpy array? So can I see it as the images getting 'merged' into one big numpy array and what your function do is to look at where each ends?

@RedSean The (1080 x1420 x 3) numpy array is one image. The 1080x1420 is height and width and the 3 is for red+green+blue. You have 8752 arrays dumped separately into your file. (Assuming they're all like the first.)

I.e. not one big NumPy array, just one big pickle file with 8752 NumPy arrays.

Oh no, with that conclusion, I can't make sure they have the same structure as the photos, can't I.

@RedSean Yes, they could all be different. Might not even be NumPy arrays. You can use type() and .shape again on each (or whatever else is appropriate if you do have other types of objects).

This made me rethinking why would the original codebase using pickle as dataset representations, do they only need the bits and binary instead of spatial context of each arrays? Btw thanks again
